# Удалить строку таблицы по регулярному выражению на php

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть простой шаблон письма:

```
<table border="0" style="background:#eee; color:#333; border:solid 1px #000000;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Резерв ТО</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Наименование</td>
        <td>ТО 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Цена</td>
        <td>103</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>%%en-input-vin.title%%</td>
        <td>%%en-input-vin.value%%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>%%en-input-model.title%%</td>
        <td>%%en-input-model.value%%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как правильно написать регулярное выражение для preg_replace(), чтобы удалить:

```
    <tr>
        <td>%%en-input-model.title%%</td>
        <td>%%en-input-model.value%%</td>
    </tr>
```

Вместе с 4-мя пробелами и переносом строки только там, где есть %%что-нибудь%%?

Comment: а не проще не писать туда уту строку вообще, зачем такой кастыль лепить?

Comment: такая задача стояла, переделываю не свои наработки.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $template = preg_replace('\'<tr>(\\s*)<td[^>]*?>%%.*?%%</td>(\\s*)</tr>\'si', "", $template);
```

Пишу ответ, так как кому-нибудь может пригодиться парсить теги и их содержимое из зараннее написанных шаблонов с форматированием с четырьмя пробелами.

Comment: Для парсинга тегов существует simpleXML.... За это и минус. Вообще это ужасные кастыли которые не достойны даже упоминания, потому как после токого охото уволиться с работы, и вообще бросить программирование...

Comment: В моём случае внутри валидных XML-тегов ещё и импровизированные шаблонные %%...%%, так что не уверен, что ваше решение подойдёт. Я не php-программист, а фронтенд, по воле случая такая задача. Если бы кто-то написал простой и краткий ответ без пафоса, как я скинул, я бы сэкономил час рабочего времени. Если не нравится вопрос - на него можно не отвечать. Я же надеюсь, что кому-нибудь (новичку) мой вопрос и ответ смогут помочь.

Comment: ваш ответ быстрее испортит жизнь и карьеру чем поможет. Стопитьсот ответов уже есть где прямо говорят не стоит юзать регулярки не стоит ((